# ClientKeyExchange does not happen after ServerHelloDone

Tags: java, ssl

I have two laptops running the same project on them. Both instances are configured to use Java JDK 6 (same minor version). However one machine is not able to connect to a remote REST service. By running applications with `-Djavax.net.debug=all` option I came to the conclusion that the issue is with the **ClientKeyExchange** step as this step does not happen on the problematic laptop.

[A post in the IBM developer community](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014026637) suggests that "hardware crypto device being used is not on the supported list". However I have no understanding about "hardware crypto devices".

What I can tell is that "enabled cipher suites", "excluded cipher suites", "cipher suites have been set to" lists printed by means of `-Djavax.net.debug=all` are the same on both machines.

Using JDK cacerts.

Comment: Hi! It would be better if you could add the actual errors exactly as printed (but possibly truncated to the relevant parts if they are very long) instead of describing them.

Comment: Only error that I got was `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class javax.crypto.SunJCE_b` and I don't think stack trace is relevant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution. Project is using JAX-RS so calls to external service happened through that framework and because of that I could not dig to the problem since there were no errors. So I tried different approach: tried to access the service by using simple `javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection` which showed me `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class javax.crypto.SunJCE_b` and therefore I changed my `local_policy.jar` and `US_export_policy.jar` files (thanks to @Charlie [Could not initialize class javax.crypto.SunJCE_b](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20994797/could-not-initialize-class-javax-crypto-sunjce-b))

I think I had changed policy jars on first laptop and forgot to do this on the new laptop.